# Flutter @dart=2.9 import 'dart:math'; Error, dart code won't run in emulator?

Tags: dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-null-safety, dart-pub

**Question:** How can I solve the flutter error as shown below & why does this happen?

*What* *I* *can't  understand out of this error, is*
that I can't comprehend what @dart=2.9 is. I hadn't previously run or coded the file in a while. So, when I came back to work on this flutter file project, it threw me this error?

I tried updating flutter on the command prompt. Everything it's fine according to the flutter doctor. The only missing piece is just visual studio, but I use visual studio Code. So, I am assuming that's not the problem. If not, then what could it be? I am deeply thinking about this long error, that can't get to comprehend.

**Much appreciation in advance** any sort of help will be gratefully appreciated

**Error:** Flutter run -
*When I run flutter run it always displays the errors below.*

```
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\14706\Desktop\Test-SETUP\New folder\This_Folder_Contains_Map_Tests_From_Top_To_Bottom_Atempts\Challenge_1\flutter_login_auth\.dart_tool\flutter_build\6494cc4bb6a11f1a583790c79662ece5\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\14706\Desktop\Test-SETUP\New folder\This_Folder_Contains_Map_Tests_From_Top_To_Bottom_Atempts\Challenge_1\flutter_login_auth\.dart_tool\flutter_build\6494cc4bb6a11f1a583790c79662ece5\kernel_snapshot.d
../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database-6.1.2/lib/firebase_database.dart:5:1: Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
// @dart=2.9
^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/Pages/auth/mainLoginCheck.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database-6.1.2/lib/src/utils/push_id_generator.dart:5:1: Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
// @dart=2.9
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database-6.1.2/lib/src/database_reference.dart:5:1: Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
// @dart=2.9
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database-6.1.2/lib/src/event.dart:5:1: Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
// @dart=2.9
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database-6.1.2/lib/src/firebase_database.dart:5:1: Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
// @dart=2.9
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database-6.1.2/lib/src/query.dart:5:1: Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
// @dart=2.9
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database-6.1.2/lib/src/on_disconnect.dart:5:1: Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
// @dart=2.9
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Unhandled exception, umm...???**
what even is this error that comes along down here?

```
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart
%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:659:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:799:2
1)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:625:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter
 (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1451:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server
/bin/
frontend_server_starter.dart:10:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\14706\Desktop\CODES\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\14706\Desktop\CODES\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             30.1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

```
Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
```

I have previoulsy tried updating flutter on command prompt. Everything it's fine according to flutter doctor. I have tried looking on what **@=dart=2.9** is? but not enought understanding still. I have also tried looking on something the error highlights which is **'dart:html';** still, I don't comprehend how and why that is an errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-just delete `import  'dart:html';` from your code

2-run `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`

if that  doesn't work check [this](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)

Comment: Thank you @ahmed, I tried doing it but it mentions to me that "lib/main.dart:19:19: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the `@dart=` annotation or setting the language version to 2.12 or higher.
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);"

Comment: @Anthony I tested on a project of mine,1- delete `//@dart=2.9` and 2- see if the `test` folder gives you an error if it does delete the file inside the folder and 3- make sure there is "?" inside ` const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);` if that work for you please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Import `'dart:math'` instead of `'dart:html'`

```
import 'dart:math'
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34732756)

Comment: @MajidHajibaba: Why not? It's making a clear proposal. It'd be more useful if the author provided an explanation, but that's not a reason to vote to delete.

Answer (score 0):

**I face this error and one solution applied to my project is to work**

1 - Install Flutter version 2.10.3

2 - Find in the Folder in Your Project Location

3 - Open in integrated Terminal

4 - Run `git checkout 2.10.3`

5 - Run `Flutter Clean` and `Flutter Pub get`